# How do you detect directional arrow keypresses in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to detect keypresses on the left and right arrow keys. Here is my current code (nothing gets printed):

```
this.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
    if (event.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        console.log("Left key");
    } else if (event.key == "ArrowRight") {
        console.log("Right key");
    }
});
```

I've tried console.log(event.key) and pressing the directional arrow buttons as well, but again, nothing gets printed.

Comment: Yes, this is explained in the very first sentence of the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) (right below the big deprecation warning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) `keypress` event is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Use `keydown` or `keyup` instead

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (event.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    console.log("Left key");
  } else if (event.key == "ArrowRight") {
    console.log("Right key");
  }
})
```